# Need Help In Proving Exact Power of Prime Divides Product Of Factorials

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing

I am trying to solve the following question:

Prove that if a and b are positive integers, p is prime, and a + b = 2p - 1 then p || a!b!. Where || means that no higher power of p will divide a!b!.

My approach was to solve for a and b, giving a = 2p - b - 1 and b = 2p - a - 1 and then trying to figure some pattern from the factorial that would allow me to factor out p exactly, but I don't think this works...any advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $b>0, a<2p-1$

If $b<p, p\nmid b!, p|| a!$

Else if $2p-1>b\ge p, p|| b!$ and $p\nmid a!$

Again $p$ can not divide both  $a!, b!$ as one of $a,b$ must be $<p$

Comment: let us take the case b < p, then b! might be larger than p, so how do you know p does not divide b!? Actually I think its because p is a prime number, so it can not be factored

Comment: @fYre,  For prime $p, p\nmid b!$ for $b<p$

Comment: I'm just thinking we know p | a! because there is definitely a p somewhere in the multiplication, for example, (p + 1)(p)(p-1)....but how do we know that (p+x)(p+y) where x and y are appropriate value will not give us for example $p^3 $, is it because $p \nmid (p + x) and (p + y)$ so there is no way we can get a $p^3$ from the factorization?

Answer (score 1):

If $a+b=2p-1$ then $a,b<2p$.

Is it possible that $a\geq p$ and $b\geq p$?

Is it possible that $a<p$ and $b<p$?

Answer (score 1):

One of $a,b$ is less than $p$ because $a+b<2 p$.It does not matter which is which so we will say that $a<p$ .And since $p$ is  a prime greater than $a$,we have $p\not| a!$.Now $p\le b<2 p$ (because $1\le a<p$ and $a+b=2 p-1$)  so the only term in the product $b!=\prod_{j=1}^{j=b} j$ which is divisible by the prime $p$ is the term $j=p$.